# yelp data set parsing json in hive

Tags: json, hive, yelp

```
create external table review
(
 business_id string,
 user_id string,
 stars Double,
 text string,
 date date,
 votes struct <
vote_type :string ,
count: int >)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'

;
```

table is loaded correctly but getting error when trying to parse stars and date field
on hive ie ..select stars from review is giving error.

data set used is used from the below link and is in json format 
https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge

Answer (score 0):

You should give pointer such as LOCATION '/user/ruchit31/god/' so that your table will point that location. Modify your create table query

```
create external table review
 ( business_id string,
 user_id string,
 stars Double,
 text string,
 date date, 
votes struct < vote_type :string , count: int >
)
 ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION '/path/'
```

Comment: location is not an issue as i am further using the command load data inpath 'path of file ' into table review.The  problem arises when retrieving data for columns which are double and date. i am not sure if am correctly using the data types needed for these fields.